# Notepad ++ How to remove all characters before and after a word

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm using regular expression in Notepad++, trying to delete everything after and before a particular word.

For example here is my text:

```
    blah blah Bull01 
    Bull02 Blah blah
    Bull03 Blah
    Blah Bull04
    Bull05 Blah
    blah blah Bull01 
    Bull02 Blah blah
    Bull03 Blah
    Blah Bull04
    Bull05 Blah
    blah blah Bull01 
    Bull02 Blah blah
    Bull03 Blah
    Blah Bull04
    Bull05 Blah
```

Im trying to delete everything before and after the word Bull, so that my results ends up being just Bull.

I tried many ways to do this using regex using something like `(?<=Bull).*` works for clearing anything after but cant get the formula to clear before.

Would anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand your full problem, but did you try replacing 
`.*Bull.*` with `Bull` ?

The replacement with `Bull` *removes* everything except `Bull` on lines containing the word `Bull`.

Comment: Doing this deletes the word bull and keeps everything else. I need the exact opposite. The only thing im trying to keep on each rows is the word Bull. For example on a row with `blah blah Bull01` I would like to only keep  Bull. I would like to do this for each rows.

Comment: Scratch that I forgot to replace it with \2 it seems to be working just doing tests now.

Comment: It can be done even simpler, we do not need the capturing groups, see the edit.